# Number formatting from 1B, 1M, 10K, etc to numbers in excel 2016

Tags: excel

I want to do something that I thought should be very simple in `Excel 2016` but seems to be running into a wall. 
The idea is to convert numbers like this

```
1B   to   1000000000
1M   to   1000000
10K  to   10000
```

I think this is fairly simple and I just miss it somehow?
Thank you! Kay

Comment: Start with this and see if you can finish it - `=IF(RIGHT(RC[-1],1)="B",1000000000*VALUE(LEFT(RC[-1],LEN(RC[-1])-1)),RC[-1])`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42472875/formula-to-convert-kg-mb-gb-tb-to-gb-in-excel/42473591#42473591

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If `Column A` contains the data, enter the below formula in `Column B` and drag down. This would work for decimals to but the result will be a string and not a number,

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1)="B",LEFT(A1,FIND("B",A1)-1)&"000000000",IF(RIGHT(A1)="M",LEFT(A1,FIND("M",A1)-1)&"000000",IF(RIGHT(A1)="K",LEFT(A1,FIND("K",A1)-1)&"000")))
```

[image]

If you want the result in a number format, just multiply the result inside the IF function by `1`. But for decimals, you cannot see the zeroes appended after the decimal point.

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1)="B",1*(LEFT(A1,FIND("B",A1)-1)&"000000000"),IF(RIGHT(A1)="M",1*(LEFT(A1,FIND("M",A1)-1)&"000000"),IF(RIGHT(A1)="K",1*(LEFT(A1,FIND("K",A1)-1)&"000"))))
```

[image]

Comment: @K.Kao Please mark my answer as correct to make this question resolved. Thats how you tell Thanks here in SO :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple vba macro that should do the trick

```
Sub replace()

Worksheets("YourSheetName").Columns("A:Z").replace What:="B", Replacement:="000000000", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

Worksheets("YourSheetName").Columns("A:Z").replace What:="M", Replacement:="000000", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

Worksheets("YourSheetName").Columns("A:Z").replace What:="K", Replacement:="000", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

End Sub
```

Note that this replaces your existing values with the new formatted ones. This is not perfect as it removes all instanses of upper case B M K in the entire sheet. You can change the `Columns("A:Z")` to just your columns with the values that need reformatting.

Comment: Thanks Felix it works well! But I ran into a problem with it. Some of my numbers have decimal like 295.96K and it will just turn into 295.96. Is there any ways to work around that?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(RIGHT(G2)="B",LEFT(G2,FIND("B",G2)-1)*"1000000000",IF(RIGHT(G2)="M",LEFT(G2,FIND("M",G2)-1)*"1000000",IF(RIGHT(G2)="K",LEFT(G2,FIND("K",G2)-1)*"1000",G2)))
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that this is unhelpfully formatted ( https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ), it lacks an explanation of how and why this helps. Without, I doubt that it helps or works at all. Please add an explanation to convince me otherwise. People are trying to edit your post to at least have decent formatting, but without an explanation it still is merely a code-only answer. Please help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free programming service, by adding an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I use Excel 2019 and I am not sure if this code I developed could help you, but I'll try  to  explain it to you so that if it doesn't work you can fix it yourself!

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1;1)="M";LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1;".";",");LEN(A1)-1)*1000000;IF(RIGHT(A1;1)="K";LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1;".";",");LEN(A1)-1)*1000;IF(RIGHT(A1;1)="B";LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1;".";",");LEN(A1)-1)*1000000000;A1)))
```

If has 3 parameters:

Condition: `RIGHT(A1;1)="M"`;

Value if true : `LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1;".";",");LEN(A1)-1)*1000000`

and Value if false : `IF... etc etc`

The condition takes the first value in the right of A1 and checks if it is equal to M.
If it is equal to M then this `SUBSTITUTE(A1;".";",")` is going to exchange all dots with commas (the way excel formats numbers 1.0 x 10 isn't a number)

this     `LEN(A1)-1` counts the number of digits -1 and `LEFT` will return the numbers in the cell -the last digit (aka M) and multiply them by 1000000.

If the condition is false then it is going to run this code: `IF(RIGHT(A1;1)="K";LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1;".";",");LEN(A1)-1)*1000;IF(RIGHT(A1;1)="B";LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1;".";",");LEN(A1)-1)*1000000000;A1))`, looping all over again for the values k and B (not case sensitive).

If all the conditions aren't satisfied then  it will return the value in cell A1.

Answer (score -1):

630.05K
672.43M
4.43B

Format to:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"B";"0000000");"M";"0000");"K";"0");".";"")
```

[image: example]